# Print Default Credentials

Tags: .net, vb.net, networkcredentials

In my VB.Net I am using the property

```
rs.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials
```

When I try to print the credentials to see my default credentials :

```
Console.WriteLine(rs.Credentials)
```

I get the output : `"System.Net.SystemNetworkCredential"`. But I would like to see the 'username' and 'password'. Could anyone tell me on how I can see the username and password ?

Comment: `DefaultCredentials` is an object of type `NetworkCredentials` (if I'm understanding the interface underneath this). As such, you should access that object's [`Password` and `UserName` properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.networkcredential?view=netframework-4.7.2) I've not used this object before though, so I may be a bit off base.

Comment: @JNevill did you even think to ask why the question is tagged as [tag:vbscript] or at the very least change the tags?

Comment: Is this a Winforms application, ASP.NET? Also, what are you trying to get this to output?  From MSDN "The ICredentials instance returned by DefaultCredentials cannot be used to view the user name, password, or domain of the current security context."  So there won't be anything to view.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.credentialcache.defaultcredentials?view=netframework-4.7.2